# Pytorch calculate loss with smaller target tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, loss-function

I am trying to fine-tune a T5 model for summarization using the following code:

```
import torch
from torchtext.models import T5_BASE_GENERATION, T5Transform
from torchtext.prototype.generate import GenerationUtils
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import json

padding_idx = 0
eos_idx = 1
max_seq_len = 16384
t5_sp_model_path = "https://download.pytorch.org/models/text/t5_tokenizer_base.model"

# Define your custom dataset class
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        example = self.data[index]
        input_text = example["input_text"]
        target_text = example["target_text"]
        return input_text, target_text

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)


# Load your labeled dataset

train_data = []  # List of labeled training examples
valid_data = []  # List of labeled validation examples

labeled = json.loads(open("data.json", 'r').read())
train_ind = range(len(labeled) - len(labeled)*0.1)
valid_ind = range(len(labeled) - len(labeled)*0.1, len(labeled))

for x in train_ind:
    print(x)
    train_data.append(labeled[str(x)])

for x in valid_ind:
    print(x)
    valid_data.append(labeled[str(x)])

# Create instances of the T5 model and transformation
t5_base = T5_BASE_GENERATION.get_model()
transform = T5Transform(sp_model_path=t5_sp_model_path, max_seq_len=max_seq_len, eos_idx=eos_idx, padding_idx=padding_idx)

# Define the training parameters
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
batch_size = 1
num_epochs = 10

# Convert your training and validation data into tensors
train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_data)
valid_dataset = CustomDataset(valid_data)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
valid_dataloader = DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

# Define the loss function and optimizer
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(t5_base.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training loop
t5_base.train()
t5_base.to(device)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    total_batches = 0

    for batch in train_dataloader:
        input_batch = []
        target_batch = []

        for input_text, target_text in zip(batch[0], batch[1]):
            input_batch.append('summarize: ' + input_text)
            target_batch.append(target_text)

        print(target_batch)

        input_batch = transform(input_batch)
        target_batch = transform(target_batch)

        input_batch = input_batch.to(device)
        target_batch = target_batch.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        sequence_generator = GenerationUtils(t5_base)
        sequence_generator.device = device

        beam_size = 1
        output = sequence_generator.generate(input_batch, eos_idx=eos_idx, num_beams=beam_size, max_length=60)

        loss = criterion(output.float().squeeze(), target_batch.view(-1))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()
        total_batches += 1

    average_loss = total_loss / total_batches
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {average_loss}")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/t5_testing/training.py", line 95, in <module>
    loss = criterion(output.float().squeeze(), target_batch.view(-1))
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1174, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3029, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
RuntimeError: size mismatch (got input: [53], target: [19])
```

Because I am fine-tuning for summarization, the target tensor is smaller than the input, so how do I calculate the loss? I want the model to output shorter summaries, but it sounds like CrossEntropyLoss requires the same input and target size. If I expand the target, will that change the content of the target?

I am new to PyTorch, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that you need to pad the output of the model with 0 to make it the same size as the reference, and avoid computing loss for the padding